# New Android Project Template Creates Fragment in Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Would anyone know why the new Android Project template create Fragments in Layout and not in Java code. Until recently when you do File->New and selcet Activity with Fragment, it creates an embedded PlaceHolderFragement that is called from the onCreate of the MainActivity.

Now it creates a FragmentView and attaches the new Fragment via layout file. I was wondering if there is a new best practice that favors creating Fragments via xml vs code.

Thanks

Comment: It is neither new nor a "best practice". Both static (`<fragment>`) and dynamic (`FragmentTransaction`) approaches have been around since fragments were introduced over four years ago. There are benefits and costs to each approach, and there is no universal "best practice" that always steers you towards one or the other.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I I try to glean crumbs of best practices from these templates. I know both has been arround however for some reason I thought the later was favored because of performing dynamic Fragment transaction aka multi-pane layouts. Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is a new best practice that favors creating
>   Fragments via xml vs code.

it is possible to declare a fragment directly in your layout using the tag `<fragment`. E.g

```
<fragment class="com.example.YourFragment"
  android:id="@+id/titles"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

using the `class` attribute you have to specify the full qualified path to  your Fragment. Be aware that the fragments declared in the layout can't be removed or replaced programmatically through transactions

Comment: Thanks, @Blackbelt, that is exactly my understanding. I was under the impression that the preferred way  of using Fragment is with Fragment Transaction because of dynamic attaching and removing them as needed for multi-pane layouts. I am sure there will be other use cases for statically attached Fragments, I was just curious if the Android Team favored a particular approach. Thanks